# SQL - Why doesn't INTERSECT equal to double JOIN?

Tags: sql

I am learning *SQL SELECT* queries and I seek for some hints :)

I found a website with tasks. When I tried to solve one of them I had two different solutions. They looked equal to me but they were not.

Could you explain me please why aren't these queries equal?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker 
FROM Product 
JOIN Laptop ON Product.model = Laptop.model 
WHERE Laptop.speed >= 750
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker
FROM Product
JOIN PC ON Product.model = PC.model
WHERE PC.speed >= 750
```

AND

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker 
FROM Product 
JOIN Laptop ON Product.model = Laptop.model
JOIN PC ON Product.model = PC.model
WHERE PC.speed >= 750 AND Laptop.speed >= 750
```

Thank you!

**update**:

one more solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product
JOIN pc ON PC.model = Product.model AND type = 'PC' AND pc.speed > = 750
WHERE maker IN
(SELECT maker FROM Product
JOIN Laptop ON Laptop.model = Product.model AND type = 'Laptop' AND Laptop.speed > = 750)
```

There is one more but **the fastest**:

```
SELECT Product.maker
FROM Product
 JOIN Laptop
 ON Product.model = Laptop.model
 AND Laptop.speed > = 750
 AND maker IN(
  SELECT maker
  FROM Product
   JOIN PC
   ON Product.model = PC.model
   AND PC.speed > = 750
 )
```

Comment: with the double join you end up with `PC.Model = Laptop.Model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersect version allows the model to differ between each of the joins, but the  single query (2nd) version requires the model to be the same.

To correct the second version, use `left join`s and move the conditions on `speed` into the join conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker 
FROM Product 
LEFT JOIN Laptop ON Product.model = Laptop.model
  AND Laptop.speed >= 750
LEFT JOIN PC ON Product.model = PC.model
  AND PC.speed >= 750
```

Comment: Product has column Type(PC or Laptop). Is it possible to specify It somehow to make the query with double join work as the query with INTERSECT?

Comment: @Donatello see edited answer for how to make single query work